# Detecting non-character press from WM_KEYDOWN message

Tags: c++, winapi

Is there a function in win32 that can take the Virtual Key code for the CTRL, ALT or capslock key & return a string saying "CTRL", "ALT", "CAPSLOCK"?

I can only receive WM_KEYDOWN messages but not WM_CHAR messages. I know I can determine what character key has been pressed by passing the Virtual Key code to the function ToUnicode() & it will tell me what character key has been pressed.

But that function returns nothing if I pass the CTRL virtual key code.

```
char keyPressed[256];
KBDLLHOOKSTRUCT kbdStruct = *((KBDLLHOOKSTRUCT*)lParam);
GetKeyboardState((PBYTE)&keyState);
ToUnicode(kbdStruct.vkCode, kbdStruct.scanCode, (PBYTE)&keyState, (LPWSTR)&keyPressed, sizeof(keyPressed) / 2, 0);    
// so if the key pressed was 'a' then keyPressed = "a";
// & if the key pressed was CTRL then keyPressed = "CTRL";
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can pass in the `lParam` value from `WM_KEYDOWN` to [`GetKeyNameText`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms646300%28v=VS.85%29.aspx) and it will return the key name for you.

Comment: "the function may give different results for different input locales". Don't expect Ctrl to be named Ctrl in german, for instance.